# шаблонный класс - друг

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как объявить в такой ситуации `A` другом `B` и можно ли использовать одинаковый параметр `t`?

```
template <typename t> class A;
template <typename t> class B
{
   public:
     friend template <typename t> class A; // <-- ошибка
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Всё ведь просто:

```
template <typename t> class A;
template <typename t> class B
{
public:
    friend class A<t>; 
};
```

---

Если нужно, чтобы другом были все `A`, а не только те, что имеют тот же шаблонный параметр, то можно написать так:

```
template <typename t> class A;
template <typename t> class B
{
public:
    template<typename>
    friend class A;
};
```

Comment: Откуда будет `t`?

Comment: @IGORb777, у Вас же класс `B` является шаблоном с одним параметром — `t`

Comment: `A<t>` будет параметризовать класс `A` типом из `B`?

Comment: @IGORb777, другом класса `B<T>` будет класс `A<T>`, где `T` это любой тип, с которым создан `B`

Comment: т.е. другом может быть только класс с тем же параметром?

Comment: @IGORb777, если написать так, то да. Вы ведь об этом явно просили

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: А ещё вопрос: как в `B` объявить функцию с параметром `A` и реализацией вне класса?

Comment: @IGORb777, задавайте новый вопрос — один пост, один вопрос.